# How the assigned value to variable gets changed automatically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, input, cin

When I am providing input for `std::cin >> diff;` it takes the input value, and the moment I am entering the value of array, the diff variables value gets changed and sets the value of `4th element` of the array.
Please help me where is it going wrong. I have tried with `fflush(std)`. But it did not help me.

I am using `Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i, num;//[]={0};
    int diff = 0;
    int numset[] = {0};
    int temp, cnt;
    cnt = num = i = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter your number and difference : ";
    //fflush(stdin);
    std::cin >> num ;
    std::cin >> diff;
    cout << "Enter array Elements : \n";
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cin >> numset[i];
        //fflush(stdin);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < num; j++)
        {

            if(i == j)
            {
                temp = numset[j];
            }
            else
            {
                if((diff == (numset[j] - temp)) || (((-1)*diff) == (numset[j] - temp)))
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << cnt << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Throwing the error as, the size of array should be greater than `0`

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is UB.

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing beyond the bounds of the array `numset`, so your code has Undefined Behaviour (UB) and anything could happen. It could overwrite variables on stack (as it does in your case), it could crash, it could order pizza online.

`numset` is declared as a single-element array, so accessing `numset[i]` for `i > 0` results in UB. You should probably change `numset` to be a `std::vector<int>` and use `push_back()` to append numbers to it.

Comment: I did understand, if I will take `vector` then things will become easy, but why is it setting the `4th element of array` to `diff` variable?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak, *It could overwrite variables on stack (as it does in your case)*

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak *Undefined behaviour is undefined.* Nevertheless, it's possible the compiler introduced some padding between stack variables, so there's the single `int` of `numset`, then 12 bytes of padding, then the single int of `diff`. So accessing `diff` can also be seen as accessing `num[4]`, and vice versa.